# javaScript: difference between class and using functions for objects?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and have some experience in C++. 
I am having difficulties in understanding using functions to create an object. In this example:

```
// 1. Create constructor function
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
// a function prototype has "constructor" property by default,
// so we don't need to create it

// 2. Add the method to prototype
User.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  alert(this.name);
};

// Usage:
let user = new User("John");
user.sayHi();
```

why do I have to add the function by setting it to the prototype of User? I tried just User.sayHi = function(){...} and it doesn't work. I don't think I understand prototypes 100%.

Comment: `User` is the "class", `user` is the instance of that "class". Doing `User.sayHi = ...` is like setting a static class function, ie you would always have to call it like `User.sayHi()` and wouldnt have access to `this.name` as it doesnt have access to an instance

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Why would User.sayHi() not have access to this.name? I am interpreting it as having a sayHi function in User, so user, the instance of User would also have a sayHi method. If not, then why does assigning it to the prototype make it work just fine?

Comment: there are other who are a lot more knowledgeable than I, but javascript doesn't have classes in the same way that c++ does. I think what you did above was attach a function to a function, rather than attach a function to a class.